# Is it possible to deploy API Gateway and Lambda in two regions with Serverless?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I'm using [serverless](https://serverless.com/) to deploy my Lambda APIs through API Gateway on AWS, but one thing that looks like is missing is the ability to deploy the Lambda API and the API Gateway into different regions. Right now, if I set the region to the `serverless deploy` command, it deploys both in that region, regardless of the fact that in the `serverless.yml` file I specified a different region for the Lambda. So let's say you have this file:

```
service: My-Awesome-API

provider:
  name: aws
  region: eu-west-1
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  memorySize: 384

functions:
  graphql:
    handler: src/index.handler
    name: My-Awesome-GraphQL-API
    events:
      - http:
          path: graphql
          method: POST
          cors: true
      - http:
          path: graphql
          method: GET
          cors: true
```

and you deploy the API with this command `serverless deploy --region=eu-central-1`.
The Lambda function will be deployed in `eu-central-1` rather than in `eu-west-1`.

Since this can be useful, and it can be done within API Gateway, is there a way to specify this behaviour with the serverless framework too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The region in the provider settings is just the default. By using the `--region` argument you overwrite that default, so the behaviour is expected.

Serverless is based on [CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/it/cloudformation/) in the background and [CloudFormation stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/stacks.html) are region-specific so there's no way in vanilla CloudFormation to deploy resources in a single stack across multiple regions.

(You can do that with custom resources though, but I would recommend against that practice except from a few edge cases.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I supposed this was more a CF limitation rather than serverless. Still could be an interesting feature having a "multi region formation" from where you can create and manage different services across multiple AWS regions

Comment: It could be interesting, but the idea of a region is to have an entity that exists independently from other regions and introducing cross-region dependencies with CloudFormation are counterproductive (although in some cases necessary as with CloudFront certificates that need to live in us-east-1).